# Calculating Kernel matrix using numpy methods

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a data of shape d X N (each column is a vector of features)
I have this code for calculating the kernel matrix:

```
def kernel(x1, x2):
  return x1.T @ x2

data = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]])
result = []
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
  current_result = []
  for j in range(data.shape[1]):
    x1 = data[:, i]
    x2 = data[:, j]
    current_result.append(kernel(x1, x2))
  result.append(current_result)

np.array(result)
```

and I am getting this result:

```
array([[ 3,  6,  9],
       [ 6, 12, 18],
       [ 9, 18, 27]])
```

The problem is that this code is too slow, so I tried to use np.vectorize:

```
vec = np.vectorize(kernel, signature='(n),(n)->()')
vec(data, data)
```

But I am getting the wrong result:

```
array([14, 14, 14])
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `np.vectorize` is not really made for making the code faster. If you want to use it for speeding up your code, this is a waste of time.

Comment: Is there another way to compute the kernel on each pair of column vectors, using numpy methods (or broadcasting)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When tested for bigger dimensions of your problem, and random numbers to ensure the robustness, for instance with dimensions `(100,200)`, there are several ways:

```
import numpy as np

def kernel(x1, x2):
    return x1.T @ x2

def kernel_kenny(a):
    result = []
    for i in range(a.shape[1]):
      current_result = []
      for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        x1 = a[:, i]
        x2 = a[:, j]
        current_result.append(kernel(x1, x2))
    
      result.append(current_result)

    return np.array(result)

a = np.random.random((100,200))

res1 = kernel_kenny(a)

# perhaps einsum signature might help you to understand the calculations
res2 = np.einsum('ji,jk->ik', a, a, optimize=True)
# or the following if you want to explicitly specify the transpose
# res2 = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', a.T, a, optimize=True)
    
# or simply ...
res3 = a.T @ a
```

Hera are the sanity checks:

```
np.allclose(res1,res2)
>>> True

np.allclose(res1,res3)
>>> True
```

and timings:

```
%timeit kernel_kenny(a)
>>> 83.2 ms ± 425 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.einsum('ji,jk->ik', a, a, optimize=True)
>>> 325 µs ± 4.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit a.T @ a
>>> 82 µs ± 9.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```